# iOS GCM push notifications does not always received in background

Tags: ios, google-cloud-messaging

I'm working on getting background notifications to work on IOS with GCM - non-background notifications are already working.

In background notifications sometimes come and sometimes not.
I used conten_available = 1;

I successfully obtained a `Registration Token` and subscribe to topic:

`Registration Token`:

> nU8ef5ZzonI:APA91bFaazXpqgI2wKTCujMaLLIZaKOmdpPAz2_WRc3V54d4eEI8p8VeAUZLwMAQ_8iaDDQ4XJAS44dFyIQkXcZ8cJjVdEGUEgnNOtrqxBKFHDTtPOUf2xT28vRprdStdVNzvrBFCQ3
>
> - Connected to GCM Sep  2 17:37:24 iPhones-iPad News[4201] : Already subscribed to /topics/news

But often in the backgrounds the application does not receive notification.
Or, the notification may come all at once old and new.
Why notification work so unstable?

Answer (score 1):

You said "But often in the backgrounds the application does not receive notification. Or, the notification may come all at once old and new.".

Meaning not that they don't come, but they are delayed. Background pushes often are not immediate delivery and may take several hours. 
If the user force quits the app they will not be delivered at all.
If you plug your iPhone into a power charger (or connect it to a computer via a charging usb cable) and try again you will most likely find they are delivered immediately. This is because starting with iOS8 background notification delivery is tied to power saving and hence why you will see them delayed and bunched together when they are delivered.